# Game crashes when launching from XCode but not when launched directly

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

Running from the device doesn't cause this issue, but when launching from Xcode I get the following in the output:

> validateIndexBuffer:132: failed assertion `indexCount(0) must be non-zero.'

and on the breakpoint I get this:

> unitygfxdeviceworker (18): signal sigabrt

No idea what's causing it...

Comment: Unity3D compile our c# scripts and make package with mono, so games run on devices. Xcode not compile c# scripts and do not work with mono. I hope my comment help you

Comment: You'll have to give a bit more information. Does this happen with an empty project, too? If not, are you using third party libraries? Can you narrow the problem down by selectively removing stuff from your game until it runs from XCode?